# Is there a way to block ALL inbound/outbound traffic going outside of a LAN with iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

As the title says, I'm just looking for a way to disallow any traffic on ANY port unless it's going to a local IP address (192.168.1.*).

Comment: Are you looking to do this to routed traffic or traffic originating from the local box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes with this :

```
iptables -P INPUT  DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT  -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp ! -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

and

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp ! -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

the first rule block the ip address with coming from other sources and the second rules block the access to destination outside `192.168.1.0/24`